# Getting an empty array while trying to return an array of JSON documents using REST extension (MarkLogic)

Tags: javascript, rest, marklogic

```
function get(context, params) {
    var max = "http://blahblah"; //declaring namespace  

    let query = []

    if (params.tokenNum) {
        query.push(cts.elementValueQuery(fn.QName(max, "TOKENUM"), params.tokenNum))
        query.push(cts.collectionQuery("WORKORDER"))
    }
    if (params.location) {
        query.push(cts.elementValueQuery(fn.QName(max, "LOC"), params.location))
        query.push(cts.collectionQuery("WORKORDER"))
    }
    if (params.Id) {
        query.push(cts.elementValueQuery(fn.QName(max, "ID"), params.Id))
        query.push(cts.collectionQuery("WORKORDER"))
    }

    let result = []

    let doc = fn.subsequence(cts.search(cts.andQuery(query)), params.start, params.length)
    const json = require('/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy');
    let config = json.config("custom");
    for (var d of doc) {
        result.push(json.transformToJson(d, config));
    }
    return result
};
```

I am trying to return an array of JSON documents using REST extension but all I am getting is an empty array I am using the URL 
    http://localhost:9015/v1/resources/location?rs:Id=ABC&rs:start=1&rs:length=10

However when I run this code in the query console by using a params object as a test like this

```
let params = {
    start: '1',
    length: '10',
    tokenNum: "100404",
    location: "0256", 
    Id: "ABC"
};
```

then I get what I am looking for(which is the array of JSON documents).

I can't figure it out what's going wrong. I would appreciate if someone can help

Comment: Does the REST call report any errors?  For instance, if you invoke it with curl -i?

(Footnote:  it would be best to add the collection query once.)

Comment: Are you authenticating as the same user when testing via QConsole and the REST extension?

Comment: @MadsHansen Yes, I am authenticating as the same user.

Comment: Looks like the port was not configured for the database that I selected in the query console that is why the query was giving results on query console and not in the browser. Sorry about that.